# carousFredSel update image container

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

What I need to have happen is when the product thumbnail is clicked the main image is updated but i can not seem to figure it out. The weird part about this is after the page has loaded, resizing the browser page seems to fire the script to re-initialize and thus updates the main image when a thumbnail is clicked.

Demo link here http://www.venaproducts.com/dev/product/fosmon-hybo-duoc-case-for-amazon-fire-phone/

Please help. I've combed through the documentation here but I must be missing something. http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel-advanced

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var allVariants = "";

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('body').append('<div id="prod_var_images" />');

            if (typeof product_variations === 'undefined') { 
                allVariants = $('form.variations_form').data('product_variations');
            } else { 
                allVariants = product_variations; 
            }

            $('input[name="variation_id"]').change( function() {
                var variantID = $(this).val();
                var variantData = "";
                for (var p = 0; p < allVariants.length; p++) {          
                    if ( allVariants[p].variation_id == variantID ) {
                        variantData = allVariants[p];
                    }           
                }

                //update SKU
                if(variantData) {
                    if(variantData.sku) {
                        $('span.prod-sku').text('SKU: ' + variantData.sku);
                        $('*[class*="variation-VN"]:not([class*="variation-' + variantData.sku + '"])').hide();
                        $('*[class*="variation-' + variantData.sku + '"]').show();
                    }
                }

                if(variantData.sku) {
                    //pull all variation images out and append to #prod_var_images div
                    $('#product-images img[alt*="variation-VN"]').closest('a').appendTo('#prod_var_images');

                    //only show main sku variation images below main images
                    $('#prod_var_images img[alt*="variation-' + variantData.sku + '"]').closest('a').appendTo($('#product-images'));

                    //reinitialize the slide for new the content
                    $('#product-images').carouFredSel({
                        reInit:true,
                        height: 'auto',
                        width: 276,
                        items: 3,
                        scroll: {
                            easing: "elastic",
                            duration: 1000 
                        },
                        circular: false,
                        auto: false,
                        swipe: {
                            onMouse: true,
                            onTouch: true
                        },
                        prev: ".product-prev",
                        next: ".product-next",
                    });

                    //rebuild thumbnail links to go to correct images - NOT WORKING
                    $('#product-images a').each(function(i) {               
                        $(this).bind('click', function() {
                            $('#product-images a').addClass('active');                      
                        });             
                    }); 
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet will update preview image by clicking on thumb with caroufredsel plugin attached on thumbs. How to work with resizing I can't tell you, read more about adaptive and responsive designs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        #gallery_01 img {
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img id='img_01' src='/small/image1.jpg' data-zoom-image='/large/image1.jpg'/>

<div id='gal1'>
    <a href='#' data-image='/small/image1.jpg' data-zoom-image='/large/image1.jpg'>
        <img src='/thumb/image1.jpg'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#' data-image='/small/image2.jpg' data-zoom-image='/large/image2.jpg'>
        <img src='thumb/image2.jpg'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#' data-image='/small/image3.jpg' data-zoom-image='/large/image3.jpg'>
        <img src='thumb/image3.jpg'/>
    </a>
    <a href='#' data-image='/small/image4.jpg' data-zoom-image='/large/image4.jpg'>
        <img id='img_01' src='thumb/image4.jpg'/>
    </a>
</div>

<div id='controls'>
    <span><a id='prev' href='#'><- Prev</a></span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span><a id='next' href='#'>Next -></a></span>
</div>

<script src='/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js'></script>
<script src='/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        var zoom_config = {
                gallery: 'gallery_01',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                galleryActiveClass: 'active',
                imageCrossfade: true
            },
            carousel_config = {
                items: 3,
                height: 100,
                width: 300,
                circular: true,
                infinite: true,
                direction: 'left',
                scroll: {items: 1, easing: 'elastic', duration: 500, pauseOnHover: true},
                prev: '#prev',
                next: '#next'
            },
            $large_image = $('#img_01'),
            $gallery = $('#gal1'),
            $thumbs = $gallery.find('a');

        $large_image.elevateZoom(zoom_config);
        $gallery.carouFredSel(carousel_config);

        $thumbs.on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var self = $(this);

            $large_image.removeData('elevateZoom');
            $large_image.attr('src', self.data('image'));
            $large_image.data('zoom-image', self.data('zoom-image'));
            $large_image.elevateZoom(zoom_config);
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```